# How can i have Fedora like system-config-*, system-config-network-tui in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, fedora

How can i have system-config-network-tui or all those system-config-* text user interfaces so that i can use or configure my Ubuntu box using SSH terminal or Serial console terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no TUI interfase in debian-like systems for system configuration (except for package configuration).

You have to edit config files. Most of them are very well commented. You can learn a lot just by reading them. Also, you can do much more. GUI interfaces are usually limited only to most popular options.

Assuming, you need to tweak SSH server and you don't know the config file location, you can find it via:

- `apropos -s 5 ssh` to list man pages from section 5 (config files) related to ssh
- `dpkg -l | grep ssh` list packages related to ssh, and then when you know the package:
- `dpkg -L openssh-server | grep conf` find config files in that package
- or you can `locate conf | grep ssh`

Once you know the config file, make backup, read it, learn and play with it.

Have fun.

Comment: Is there no one/anything else for Ubuntu as TUI's, at-least for doing most common modules? Because in Fedora it still keep the traditional TUI, for important modules such as IP settings very common use.